# Given two column vectors $a$ and $b$, what is the determinant of $A$ if $A=ab^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given two column vectors $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R^n$
, $n \ge 2$, form the $n×n$ matrix
$A = ab^T$. What is the determinant of $A$?

(Hint: Examine linear
dependence).

Comment: Try a few simple cases in say, $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. You'll see a definite pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always be the case that $\det(ab^T) = 0$.

Let $a =\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $b =\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$.  We have $\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \\ 
\end{pmatrix}^T$ =\begin{pmatrix}
a_1b_1        & \ldots & a_1b_n  \\
a_2b_1      & \dots    & a_2b_n   \\
\vdots        &\vdots & \vdots \\
a_nb_1 & \ldots & a_nb_n
\end{pmatrix}

Recall that multiplying a single row of a matrix by a scalar $c$ has the effect of changing the determinant by a factor of $c$.  Hence,
$$\det(ab^T) = \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i \bigg) \det\begin{pmatrix}
b_1        & \ldots & b_n  \\
b_1      & \dots    & b_n   \\
\vdots        &\vdots & \vdots \\
b_1 & \ldots & b_n
\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)^T$ and $b=(b_1,\dots,b_n)^T$, then the product $ab^T$ is the $n\times n$ matrix
$$ab^T = \begin{pmatrix}a_1b_1&\cdots& a_1b_n\\
a_2b_1&\cdots& a_2b_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the first row is a multiple of the second, so the matrix has rank $< n$, meaning the determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Two useful facts.

[The inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties)
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)
$$
for matrices of compatible shapes tells you that $AB$ has rank at most $1$, and thus zero determinant, as $n > 1$.

One actually has (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Alternative_definitions) under *tensor rank – minimum number of simple tensors*) that a matrix has rank at most $1$ precisely when it can be written as the product of a column vector and a row vector.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully by now you've solved the question.I'll post this anyways.

Take a vector $a=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}$ and multiply it by any matrix $b^T$ which is $1\times n$.i.e $b^T=\begin{pmatrix}b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\end{pmatrix}$

Then  one observes that the columns of $ab^t$ are linear multiples of a and the rows are linear multiples of b.Using this we conclude that the determinant is $0$, as it has only one independent row.

In general, the matrix $AB$ has columns which are linear combinations of those of A and rows, linear combinations of those of $B$.